# Django Queryset, accessing all query except those belongs to logged users?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i know this:

```
queryset = Item.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I want query for opposite of that, where i get Items of all user except logged one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite of filter is `exclude`:

```
queryset = Item.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user)
```